# How to put array in csv using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach

I am trying to pass associative arrays to a csv file, I am attaching an example of the array. The keys are the same for all registers and would be the first line of the csv.

```
Array
(
    [operation] => Alquiler
    [provider] => MERCADOLIBRE
    [date_day] => 2020-06-01
    [Type] => Departamento
    [Location] => VILLA BOSCH (PDO. DE TRES DE FEBRERO)
    [Neighborhood] => Villa Bosch
    [Environments] => 2 AMBIENTES
    [ValueRent] => 9000
    [SalesValue] => 0
)
Array
(
    [operation] => Alquiler
    [provider] => MERCADOLIBRE
    [date_day] => 2020-06-01
    [Type] => Casa
    [Location] => Caseros
    [Neighborhood] => 
    [Environments] => 3 AMBIENTES
    [ValueRent] => 19500
    [SalesValue] => 0
)
```

I leave the code where I generate the array:

```
$data = mysqli_query("SELECT s.codemp,s.ficha,s.operacion AS operation,s.proveedor AS provider,s.fecha_dia as date_day FROM control.solicitudes AS s WHERE fecha_dia >= '2020-06-01' AND ficha != '' LIMIT 50");

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {

    $query_check = mysqli_query('SELECT i.in_tip as Type,i.in_loc as Location,i.in_bar as Neighborhood,a.ti_des as Environments,i.in_vaa as ValueRent,i.in_val as SalesValue FROM '.strtolower($r['codemp']).'.kkinmu AS i INNER JOIN '.strtolower($r['codemp']).'.kkambi AS a ON i.in_amb = a.ti_tip   WHERE i.in_fic = "'.strtolower($r['ficha']).'"');
   
    while ($r2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_check)) {
        $r += $r2;
        unset($r['codemp']);
        unset($r['ficha']);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to start off using `fputcsv`. and by the way, try try to avoid queries under another query, instead try to use joins

Comment: And what's your question about this? Anything not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// Let your input array be like:
$arr = [
[
    "operation" => "Alquiler",
    "provider" => "MERCADOLIBRE",
    "date_day" => "2020-06-01",
    "Type" => "Departamento",
    "Location" => "VILLA BOSCH (PDO. DE TRES DE FEBRERO)",
    "Neighborhood" => "Villa Bosch",
    "Environments" => "2 AMBIENTES",
    "ValueRent" => "9000",
    "SalesValue" => "0",
],
[
    "operation" => "Alquiler",
    "provider" => "MERCADOLIBRE",
    "date_day" => "2020-06-01",
    "Type" => "Casa",
    "Location" => "Caseros",
    "Neighborhood" => "",
    "Environments" => "3 AMBIENTES",
    "ValueRent" => "19500",
    "SalesValue" => "0",
]
];

// get the header row from the input array
$hearders = array_keys(current($arr));

// open a file for writing
$fh = fopen("test.csv", "w");
// write header row
fputcsv($fh, $hearders);

// loop through the input array and write each row to the file.
foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
    fputcsv($fh, $row);
}

// close the file handle.
fclose($fh);
```

Read more about [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Read more about [open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)